# Automating domain adding and verification steps to use Google Calendar's Push notifications

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, push-notification, google-calendar-api, webhooks

I'm trying to build a rails application which will use Google Calendar to schedule meetings with people.  People should be able to associate a Calendar (shared calendar), create an event in that calendar and invite people. If attendees respond (responseStatus update) from their calendars to the invitation, I want to get notified in the application via webhook to achieve Two-way sync.

This use case can be achieved by enabling [Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push) and by "[watching](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/watch)" the event, but the problem is I need to manually register and verify the domain (in the Google Developer console) to which the webhooks are sent.

Can this be automated? Because in my use case, there will be multiple applications, each one with a different domain. I want to automate the adding and verifying the domain process, as the application knows the domain by itself. I don't want the end users to do this manually as this is going to be used by non-tech ppl and I want to make the process simple - I want the sync to be enabled in a single click. I think this is a very usual use case and many people would have faced it. Can you guys help me solve this problem?

Also, if I solve this problem, I needn't use repeated polling to update the events. Do we have any other way to achieve this use case, if Google doesn't support domain adding via API?

**UPDATE:**

My application domains are going to be subdomains of a main domain. From this [link](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35163?hl=en&ref_topic=4564314&vid=1-635796479292102918-3720802661), if I do a DNS verification of the domain once, all its subdomains and subdirectories are verified. So verification shouldn't be a problem. I need a solution to add the domain to the Developer console.

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue. I'm also stuck in a similar kind of situation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is link from official google site to verify subdomain.  https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35163?hl=en&ref_topic=4564314&vid=1-635796479292102918-3720802661

Answer (score 0):

I've created a [simple node package](https://github.com/brh55/google-domain-verify) to allow you to do it with a few commands (although you need to be comfortable with running a few copy paste commands), since I too was having issues with setting up a verified domain and instructing my team members repeatingly. Although your thing may require a bit of customized work to create a UI and an accompany server to hook into.